# Slowing Addition the Closer It Gets to Its Max Assigned Value

Tags: javascript, math

Okay, this question is going to have to be visualized with some pseudo-code, so here we go:

Lets say I have 2 integers, one is a varible, the other a constant.

With this say:

```
int current = 0; static int max = 20
```

With this in mind, how would I add slower, the closer I get to 20, so basically it never actually reaches 20.
Here is an example:

lets say adding 2 takes 3 seconds
but adding the same 2, after the previous 2 takes twice as long, and so on.

How would I go about doing this, sorry if its hard to understand, but I tried my best :(

Thanks, and have a great day!

Comment: You could use any number of different equation sets depending on how you want your function to work, a [logarithmic](http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/17-exponentials-logarithms/06-population-exponential-growth-01) function is most likely what you're looking for.

Comment: The formula is similar to one of calculating continuously compounding interest.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful but keep adding half (or third or ... depending on how slow you want it to be) the gap between `current` and `max` like this: `curent += (max - current) / 2;`!

Answer (score 0):

An example to play around with.

```js
function progressiveInterpolatorThatNeverReachesTheEnd(rate, speed){
  speed = +speed || 1;
  var start = Date.now();
  
  return function(a, b){
    var time = (Date.now() - start);
    var t = Math.pow(1-rate, time * speed/1000);
 
    return a*t + b*(1-t);
  }
}

var start = Date.now();
var interpolate = progressiveInterpolatorThatNeverReachesTheEnd(1/16, 1/10);

var output = document.getElementById("output");

function update(){
  var a = 0, b = 100, c = interpolate(a, b);
  output.innerHTML = a + " .. " + Math.floor(c) + " .. " + b + "<br> actually: " + c + "<br>runtime: " + (Date.now() - start)/1000 + "s";

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  //or
  //setTimeout(update, Math.random() * 500); 
  //because update interval doesn't matter
}
update();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Actually, this code will eventually reach the end due to the limited precision of Numbers in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula

A = Pe<sup>rt</sup>

where `A` is resulting amount; `P` is starting principal; `e` is the mathematical irrational constant `e`, the base of natural logarithms, commonly referred to as Euler's Number, approximately `2.718281828459045`; `r` is rate of interest as a decimal; `t` is time in years, generally divided by `360`.

Given a starting principal of `0` the result would be `0`, as no interest can accrue an a principal of `0`. We can begin at the nominal value of `.01`, then set the new principal to the result of the accrued interest added to the previous principal.

In `javascript` a `do..while` loop can be used to generate the new principal, here, we stop the loop at half the starting rate, or `.05/2` Within `do..while` loop create an immediately invoke function expression to pass current principal, push a function which returns a `Promise` after `current` or `current * duration`, where `duration` is a positive integer, utilize `Array.prototype.reduce()` to call function which returns a `Promise` in sequential order, increasing duration of next `setTimeout` by `current` or `current * duration`.

You can also adjust formula to `Math.exp(r * (t/n))` or

A = Pe<sup>r(t/n)</sup>

where `n` could be, for example, `360`, to compound interest continuously from principal `1` at rate of `.05`, execute `do..while` loop `360` times, a fiscal year; which would produce a greater amount of total results between `1`, that is `1` continuously compounded for 1 year at rate of `5%` where the maximum possible result would be `1.0512710963760241`, total interest accrued being `.0512710963760241`.

Passing `1` to `compound` function returns `1.0512710963760241`.

```js
var current = 0; // principal
var max = 20; // maturity, in years
var rate = .05; // annual rate as decimal
var time = 1; // time in years, alternatively `1/360`
var N = 360; // fiscal year
var arr = []; // store functions which return a `Promise`
var duration = 500;
var output = document.querySelector("output");

function compound(p, r, t) {  
  return ((p||.01) * Math.exp(r * t)); // or `Math.exp(r * (t/N))` 
}

do {
  current = compound(current, rate, time);
   (function(curr) {
    arr.push(
      function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            output.innerHTML += `current principal: ${curr}<br>`;
            resolve();
          }, curr * duration)
        })
      }
    )
   })(current)
} while (current < max - (rate / 2));

arr.reduce(function(promise, next) {
  return promise.then(next)
}, Promise.resolve())
.then(function() {
   output.innerHTML += `<br>max - current: ${max - current}`; 
});
```

```html
<output></output>
```