# How to calculate weighted center point of 4 points?

Tags: javascript, math

If I have 4 points

```
        var x1;
        var y1;
        var x2;
        var y2;
        var x3;
        var y3;
        var x4;
        var y4;
```

that make up a box. So

```
(x1,y1) is top left
(x2,y2) is top right
(x3,y3) is bottom left
(x4,y4) is bottom right
```

And then each point has a weight ranging from 0-522. How can I calculate a coordinate (tx,ty) that lies inside the box, where the point is closer to the the place that has the least weight (but taking all weights into account). So for example. if (x3,y3) has weight 0, and the others have weight 522, the (tx,ty) should be (x3,y3). If then (x2,y2) had weight like 400, then (tx,ty) should be move a little closer towards (x2,y2) from (x3,y3).

Does anyone know if there is a formula for this?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "closer"? The pattern resembles "cartesian", or xy, coordinates. What is the graph of "weight"s?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to explain, but the (tx,ty) should be at a point where the weights are closer to 0. It's kinda like saying when the weight is 0, the corner has higher gravity (i.e. the weight corresponds to its strength of pulling). Where would a point be if its subject to gravity pulling it from all corners?

Comment: If subject to equidistant gravitational pulls, without other factors, the equilibrium would be the center. What is the formula for movement of the point?

Comment: How would you calculate that, can you show an example? Also its not the case that the gravity is equally as strong from all corners, each gravity has unique strength.

Comment: You can calculate any point on a graph using x,y, or x,y,z coordinates and trigonometry.

Comment: Are to box sides parallel to coordinate axes? For example is x1==x3?

Comment: I'm also not sure what formula you refer too, I think there is no formula for the movement, the point should just lie at a place where it feels an equal pull from all directions, that's what I think the place of stability is. That is the (tx,ty) I'm looking for how to calculate.

Comment: @Luka, yes x1==x3. It is a rectangle (not some rhombus)

Comment: Convert http://stackoverflow.com/q/18591964/215552 to JavaScript. There's also myriad formulae on the internet, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon).

Comment: I guess you need some formula which will approximate behavior that you just described? What is one of the weights, w1=0. Does this mean your resulting point must be (x1,y1), or just close to it? What if w1=0 and w2=0?

Comment: well I think if w1=0, and all others are max weight, then the target should be w1. But the target point doesn't have to be at a corner specifically. It can be at any location within the box.

Comment: Essentially `a^2+b^2=c^2` provides angle of linear paths where two sides of a triangle, or planes, of given distance, are known, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451882/javascript-math-functions-doesnt-make-sense#comment72048056_42451882. You can add a "weight", at a predetermined calibration, to influence, or plot the movement of a point on a graph. Whether that "weight" is constant or dynamic in relation to the point.

Comment: Can you show example code?

Comment: That would require some preparation and a framework with defined parameters. Can you include full `html`, if any, and `javascript` that you have tried at Question? What are the weights of the "gravitational pull"s? An example of using the mathematical irrational  constant `e` to get close to a limit, without actually reaching the limit [Slowing Addition the Closer It Gets to Its Max Assigned Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183231/slowing-addition-the-closer-it-gets-to-its-max-assigned-value/42184414)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `w1`, `w2`, `w3`, `w4` are the weights.
You can start with this (pseudocode):

```
M = 522
a = 1
b = 1 / ( (1 - w1/M)^a + (1 - w2/M)^a + (1 - w3/M)^a + (1 - w4/M)^a )

tx = b * (x1*(1-w1/M)^a + x2*(1-w2/M)^a + x3*(1-w3/M)^a + x4*(1-w4/M)^a)
ty = b * (y1*(1-w1/M)^a + y2*(1-w2/M)^a + y3*(1-w3/M)^a + y4*(1-w4/M)^a)
```

This should approximate the behavior you want to accomplish. For the simplest case set `a=1` and your formula will be simpler. You can adjust behavior by changing `a`.

Make sure you use `Math.pow` instead of `^` if you use Javascript.

Comment: How does `a` affect it?

Comment: It just provides you a leeway to adjust behavior to your liking. Notice that `1-w1/M` is number between `0` and `1`. Raising that number to some `a` will leave this to be between `0` and `1`. If you don't need to adjust, just set `a=1` and formula will become much simpler.

Comment: Does it mean like the bigger a is, the more amplified the gravity is?

Comment: Yes. the bigger `a` is, you'll go closer to the point with smallest weight

Comment: This did the trick, and I like that I can amplify the gravity, that actually helped.

Answer (score 2):

**Creating a minimum, complete, verifiable exmample**

You have a little bit of a tricky problem here, but it's really quite fun. There might be better ways to solve it, but I found it most reliable to use `Point` and `Vector` data abstractions to model the problem better

I'll start with a really simple data set – the data below can be read (eg) Point *D* is at cartesian coordinates (1,1) with a *weight* of 100.

```
|
|
| B(0,1) #10        D(1,1) #100
|                
| 
|         ? solve weighted average
|
| 
| A(0,0) #20        C(1,0) #40
+----------------------------------
```

**Here's how we'll do it**

1. find the unweighted midpoint, `m`
2. convert each Point to a Vector of `Vector(degrees, magnitude)` using `m` as the origin
3. add all the Vectors together, `vectorSum`
4. divide `vectorSum`'s magnitude by the total magnitude
5. convert the vector to a point, `p`
6. offset `p` by unweighted midpoint `m`

---

**Possible JavaScript implementation**

I'll go thru the pieces one at a time then there will be a complete runnable example at the bottom.

The `Math.atan2`, `Math.cos`, and `Math.sin` functions we'll be using return answers in radians. That's kind of a bother, so there's a couple helpers in place to work in degrees.

```
// math
const pythag = (a,b) => Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
const rad2deg = rad => rad * 180 / Math.PI
const deg2rad = deg => deg * Math.PI / 180
const atan2 = (y,x) => rad2deg(Math.atan2(y,x))
const cos = x => Math.cos(deg2rad(x))
const sin = x => Math.sin(deg2rad(x))
```

Now we'll need a way to represent our `Point` and Point-related functions

```
// Point
const Point = (x,y) => ({
  x,
  y,
  add: ({x: x2, y: y2}) =>
    Point(x + x2, y + y2),
  sub: ({x: x2, y: y2}) =>
    Point(x - x2, y - y2),
  bind: f =>
    f(x,y),
  inspect: () =>
    `Point(${x}, ${y})`
})

Point.origin = Point(0,0)
Point.fromVector = ({a,m}) => Point(m * cos(a), m * sin(a))
```

And of course the same goes for `Vector` – strangely enough adding Vectors together is actually easier when you convert them back to their *x* and *y* cartesian coordinates. other than that, this code is pretty straightforward

```
// Vector
const Vector = (a,m) => ({
  a,
  m,
  scale: x =>
    Vector(a, m*x),
  add: v =>
    Vector.fromPoint(Point.fromVector(Vector(a,m)).add(Point.fromVector(v))),
  inspect: () =>
    `Vector(${a}, ${m})`
})

Vector.zero = Vector(0,0)
Vector.fromPoint = ({x,y}) => Vector(atan2(y,x), pythag(x,y))
```

Lastly we'll need to represent our data above in JavaScript and create a function which calculates the weighted point. With `Point` and `Vector` by our side, this will be a piece of cake

```
// data
const data = [
  [Point(0,0), 20],
  [Point(0,1), 10],
  [Point(1,1), 100],
  [Point(1,0), 40],
]

// calc weighted point
const calcWeightedMidpoint = points => {
  let midpoint = calcMidpoint(points)
  let totalWeight = points.reduce((acc, [_, weight]) => acc + weight, 0)
  let vectorSum = points.reduce((acc, [point, weight]) =>
    acc.add(Vector.fromPoint(point.sub(midpoint)).scale(weight/totalWeight)), Vector.zero)
  return Point.fromVector(vectorSum).add(midpoint)
}

console.log(calcWeightedMidpoint(data))
// Point(0.9575396819442366, 0.7079725827019256)
```

---

**Runnable script**

```js
// math
const pythag = (a,b) => Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
const rad2deg = rad => rad * 180 / Math.PI
const deg2rad = deg => deg * Math.PI / 180
const atan2 = (y,x) => rad2deg(Math.atan2(y,x))
const cos = x => Math.cos(deg2rad(x))
const sin = x => Math.sin(deg2rad(x))

// Point
const Point = (x,y) => ({
  x,
  y,
  add: ({x: x2, y: y2}) =>
    Point(x + x2, y + y2),
  sub: ({x: x2, y: y2}) =>
    Point(x - x2, y - y2),
  bind: f =>
    f(x,y),
  inspect: () =>
    `Point(${x}, ${y})`
})

Point.origin = Point(0,0)
Point.fromVector = ({a,m}) => Point(m * cos(a), m * sin(a))

// Vector
const Vector = (a,m) => ({
  a,
  m,
  scale: x =>
    Vector(a, m*x),
  add: v =>
    Vector.fromPoint(Point.fromVector(Vector(a,m)).add(Point.fromVector(v))),
  inspect: () =>
    `Vector(${a}, ${m})`
})

Vector.zero = Vector(0,0)
Vector.unitFromPoint = ({x,y}) => Vector(atan2(y,x), 1)
Vector.fromPoint = ({x,y}) => Vector(atan2(y,x), pythag(x,y))


// data
const data = [
  [Point(0,0), 20],
  [Point(0,1), 10],
  [Point(1,1), 100],
  [Point(1,0), 40],
]

// calc unweighted midpoint
const calcMidpoint = points => {
  let count = points.length;
  let midpoint = points.reduce((acc, [point, _]) => acc.add(point), Point.origin)
  return midpoint.bind((x,y) => Point(x/count, y/count))
}

// calc weighted point
const calcWeightedMidpoint = points => {
  let midpoint = calcMidpoint(points)
  let totalWeight = points.reduce((acc, [_, weight]) => acc + weight, 0)
  let vectorSum = points.reduce((acc, [point, weight]) =>
    acc.add(Vector.fromPoint(point.sub(midpoint)).scale(weight/totalWeight)), Vector.zero)
  return Point.fromVector(vectorSum).add(midpoint)
}

console.log(calcWeightedMidpoint(data))
// Point(0.9575396819442366, 0.7079725827019256)
```

Going back to our original visualization, everything looks right!

```
|
|
| B(0,1) #10        D(1,1) #100
|
|
|                 * <-- about right here
|
| 
| 
| A(0,0) #20        C(1,0) #40
+----------------------------------
```

---

**Checking our work**

Using a set of points with *equal* weighting, we know what the weighted midpoint should be. Let's verify that our two primary functions `calcMidpoint` and `calcWeightedMidpoint` are working correctly

```
const data = [
  [Point(0,0), 5],
  [Point(0,1), 5],
  [Point(1,1), 5],
  [Point(1,0), 5],
]

calcMidpoint(data)
// => Point(0.5, 0.5)

calcWeightedMidpoint(data)
// => Point(0.5, 0.5)
```

Great! Now we'll test to see how some other weights work too. First let's just try all the points but one with a *zero* weight

```
const data = [
  [Point(0,0), 0],
  [Point(0,1), 0],
  [Point(1,1), 0],
  [Point(1,0), 1],
]

calcWeightedMidpoint(data)
// => Point(1, 0)
```

Notice if we change that weight to some ridiculous number, it won't matter. Scaling of the vector is based on the point's *percentage* of weight. If it gets 100% of the weight, it (the point) will not pull the weighted midpoint past (the point) itself

```
const data = [
  [Point(0,0), 0],
  [Point(0,1), 0],
  [Point(1,1), 0],
  [Point(1,0), 1000],
]

calcWeightedMidpoint(data)
// => Point(1, 0)
```

Lastly, we'll verify one more set to ensure weighting is working correctly – this time we'll have two pairs of points that are equally weighted. The output is *exactly* what we're expecting

```
const data = [
  [Point(0,0), 0],
  [Point(0,1), 0],
  [Point(1,1), 500],
  [Point(1,0), 500],
]

calcWeightedMidpoint(data)
// => Point(1, 0.5)
```

---

**Millions of points**

Here we will create a huge point cloud of random coordinates with random weights. If points are random and things are working correctly with our function, the answer should be pretty close to `Point(0,0)`

```
const RandomWeightedPoint = () => [
  Point(Math.random() * 1000 - 500, Math.random() * 1000 - 500),
  Math.random() * 1000
]

let data = []
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++)
  data[i] = RandomWeightedPoint()

calcWeightedMidpoint(data)
// => Point(0.008690554978970092, -0.08307212085822799)
```

A++

Comment: This answer is a slightly inaccurate right now. I'm working on fixing it.

Comment: @omega, I'm happy to help. Thru working on this, I get the sense that there's a way to simplify the problem, tho I'm not mathy enough to know exactly how. I also wouldn't be surprised if it breaks with certain inputs.

Comment: To answer you other question, it doesn't matter which point is considered the "top left" – all points are treated as a cloud of points (you could have as many as you want too, not just 4) and the weighted midpoint should still be calculated

Comment: @omega I did a little more bug-hunting on this and ironed out a couple issues. If you ended up using this, make sure to grab the updated code. There's a "check your work" section I added at the bottom of the answer that validates a series of inputs.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I re-used your test cases for my own answer to this question. If that's a problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this has already been answered, I feel the *one, short* code snippet that shows the simplicity of calculating a weighted-average is missing:

```
function weightedAverage(v1, w1, v2, w2) {
  if (w1 === 0) return v2;
  if (w2 === 0) return v1;
  return ((v1 * w1) + (v2 * w2)) / (w1 + w2);
}
```

Now, to make this specific to your problem, you have to apply this to your points via a reducer. The reducer makes it a moving average: the value it returns **represents the weights of the points it merged**.

```
// point: { x: xCoordinate, y: yCoordinate, w: weight }
function avgPoint(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: weightedAverage(p1.x, p1.w, p2.x, p2.w),
    x: weightedAverage(p1.x, p1.w, p2.x, p2.w),
    w: p1.w + p2.w,
  }
}
```

Now, you can reduce any list of points to get an average coordinate and the weight it represents:

```
[ /* points */ ].reduce(avgPoint, { x: 0, y: 0, w: 0 })
```

I hope user [naomik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633183/naomik) doesn't mind, but I used some of their test cases in this runnable example:

```js
function weightedAverage(v1, w1, v2, w2) {
  if (w1 === 0) return v2;
  if (w2 === 0) return v1;
  return ((v1 * w1) + (v2 * w2)) / (w1 + w2);
}

function avgPoint(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: weightedAverage(p1.x, p1.w, p2.x, p2.w),
    y: weightedAverage(p1.y, p1.w, p2.y, p2.w),
    w: p1.w + p2.w,
  }
}

function getAvgPoint(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(avgPoint, {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 0
  });
}


const testCases = [
  { 
    data: [
      { x: 0, y: 0, w: 1 },
      { x: 0, y: 1, w: 1 },
      { x: 1, y: 1, w: 1 },
      { x: 1, y: 0, w: 1 },
    ],
    result: { x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }
  },
  
  { 
    data: [
      { x: 0, y: 0, w: 0 },
      { x: 0, y: 1, w: 0 },
      { x: 1, y: 1, w: 500 },
      { x: 1, y: 0, w: 500 },
    ],
    result: { x: 1, y: 0.5 }
  }
];

testCases.forEach(c => {
  var expected = c.result;
  var outcome = getAvgPoint(c.data);

  console.log("Expected:", expected.x, ",", expected.y);
  console.log("Returned:", outcome.x, ",", outcome.y);
  console.log("----");
});



const rndTest = (function() {
  const randomWeightedPoint = function() {
    return {
      x: Math.random() * 1000 - 500,
      y: Math.random() * 1000 - 500,
      w: Math.random() * 1000
    };
  };

  let data = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++)
    data[i] = randomWeightedPoint()

  return getAvgPoint(data);
}());

console.log("Expected: ~0 , ~0, 500000000")
console.log("Returned:", rndTest.x, ",", rndTest.y, ",", rndTest.w);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to have made any contribution to this wonderful answer. I had a good feeling there was a way to simplify the problem but I want sure it was possible via direct calculations on x and y coordinates. Very well done.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach is this:

1. Convert each point's weight to 522 minus the actual weight.
2. Multiply each x/y co-ordinate by its adjusted weight.
3. Sum all multiplied x/y co-ordinates together, and --
4. Divide by the total *adjusted* weight of all points to get your adjusted average position.

That should produce a point with a position that is biased proportionally towards the "lightest" points, as described.  Assuming that weights are prefixed w, a quick snippet (followed by JSFiddle example) is:

```
var tx = ((522-w1)*x1 + (522-w2)*x2 + (522-w3)*x3 + (522-w4)*x4) / (2088-(w1+w2+w3+w4));
var ty = ((522-w1)*y1 + (522-w2)*y2 + (522-w3)*y3 + (522-w4)*y4) / (2088-(w1+w2+w3+w4));
```

[JSFiddle example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/sxy5w9ue/1)

Comment: Can you show example code for this? (or even pseudocode)